# chdir() functions with flag "-"; cd -

Tags: c, linux, built-in, cd

I'm implementing a Linux shell-like program. I'm writing the `cd` built-in command.

I want to support the addition of these flags: `.`, `..`, `-`, `~`.

I'm currently using the `chdir()` function, and I noticed it works well with `.`, `..`, (correct me if I'm wrong).
But, with `-`, `~` it has no effect. Both are I type them alone, aka: `cd ~`, `cd –`, and both in more complex combinations.

Could anyway tell me why this is this? And how could I solve this?

Specifically, the `~` would be easy to solve, I could get the home directory and simply redirect.
In terms of `-`, it would be more complicated, I would have to store the most previous path and always update when there is a change, not ideal.

Does anyone have a better idea of how to implement the flags?

Thanks

Comment: The `.` and `..` directories are part of the standard filesystems, which is why they work without any problems. But `cd -` and the whole `~` behavior is part of the shell and have to be handled explicitly by your shell code.

Comment: What you described is how shells solve `-` and `~`, too. There's no better way than what you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wordexp()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to expand a string like the shell does.  It handles `~`, backtick command substitution, `$(command)` substitution, environment variables, and so on; see the [man 3 wordexp](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) man page for details.

This is a function built in to the Linux standard C library (and is available in all POSIXy operating systems; it is not Linux-specific).